# How do I install NVIDIA drivers on an AWS EC2 g4dn instance

Tags: nvidia, graphics, amazon-ec2, aws

I have a G4DN instance running but I wanted to know how to install the NVIDIA drivers on it so I can get access to the complete processing power of the instance. It is running Ubuntu 20 focal and is a g4dn 4xlarge instance.

I followed the instructions to use GRID drivers here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-nvidia-driver.html#nvidia-GRID-driver

But I still get errors. For example, after running `aws s3 cp --recursive s3://ec2-linux-nvidia-drivers/latest/ .` I get

```
    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: 
RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.3) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a 
supported version!
```

Comment: see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-nvidia-driver.html

Comment: Please go through the complete post. I have already mentioned I was following the instructions from that website but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56155627/15353043). You might have to update your requests:

```
  pip3 install requests
```